# Название улицы Сергеева-Ценского сокращенно

Tags: untagged

Улица Сергеева-Ценского. В сокращенном виде: С.-Ценского?

Answer (score 1):

Фамилию в топониме нужно писать **полностью**. Допустимые виды *сокращений* в таких названиях крайне ограничены и обычно регламентируются городской топонимической комиссией (как в отношении правил местного значения, так и для конкретных исключений). Пример документа, действовавшего в Петербурге: http://docs.cntd.ru/document/8339477

Определены такие элементы топонима как (1) статусная часть (напр. улица), (2) основная часть (напр. имени кого), (3) порядковый номер и (4) определяющее слово (напр. Малая-). Для *основной* части топонима (в вашем примере это "Сергеева-Ценского") допускается сокращение только в *имени* (не в фамилии), причем *только для неформального употребления* топонима (в художественных текстах и т. п. материалах). При этом в одних случаях допускается сокращение до одной буквы  (ул. *А. Блока*), в других (*Дж. Рида*) - до двух букв, а в неочевидных случаях (*Белы Куна*) сокращение не допускается. Поэтому с точки зрения этого документа в вашем случае (составная фамилия-псевдоним) сокращение было бы *недопустимым*. Маловероятно, чтобы в каком-либо документе местного значения такая возможность рассматривалась как корректная.

Comment: Поддержал ответ, но хочу оставить пару комментариев общего плана. Употребление псевдонима "С. Ценский" было широко распространено 100 лет тому (благодаря самому С.Н. и, в особенности, М.Горькому) и держалось до конца прошлого века, например как стандартное написание автора цитаты в различных учебниках по лингвистике (дефис всё чаще появляется в более поздних изданиях и я не уверен, что это правильно).

Comment: По поводу названия улиц: сокращённое написание изредка (и, думаю, по ошибке) попадается в добротных изданиях, но особенно удивляет, насколько часто в интернете люди, живущие на таких улицах, употребляют сокращение "ул. С.-Ценского". Это требует какого-то более разумного объяснения, чем просто ошибочное написание.

Comment: "С.Ценский" - это _ранний_ псевдоним Сергеева(-Ценского). Топоним, скорее всего, был сформирован по окончательному псевдониму.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите полностью. Сократить, если места мало, можно только слово "улица" - до "ул.".

Не бывает у названий улиц сокращений. В разговоре могут отбросить имя ("улица Эйзенштейна" вместо "улица Сергея Эйзенштейна") или сократить его в письменном тексте ("ул. С. Эйзенштейна"), что тоже неправильно, но хотя бы понятно.
А то, что вы предлагаете - это, простите, ни в какие ворота не лезет...

Comment: Встречала такое написание, как я указала.... Как это не бывает сокращений? ул. Карла Маркса не сокращается до К. Маркса разве, к примеру?Если в таблице мало места..... Что делать в таком случае...?

Comment: Нет. Топоним соркращать подобным образом нельзя. Точно также нельзя сокращать "М. Горький", даже если это не улица. А то что "встречали", так, простите, на заборе можно и не то еще встретить.

Comment: А что такое таблица? Если это, предположим, расписание, автобуса... Да, в таких ситуациях правила систематически не выдерживаются, но это не проблема правил. Есть, правда, еще всякие энциклопедические издания, там тоже любят сокращать, но не думаю, что даже там до такого додумаются.